# Better SQL pagination technique

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there a better way to do paging in SQL server?

For example, I have to add @skip to @take using the following technique:

```
;WITH tmp_cte AS (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastName) AS RowNumber,
        LastName, 
        FirstName
   FROM person.Person
  WHERE FirstName like '%ad%'
)
SELECT * 
FROM tmp_cte 
WHERE RowNumber > @skip --10 
AND RowNumber <= @Take--20
```

is there a better way so that I don't have to add skip to take?

Comment: The main performance problem is going to be the `FirstName like '%ad%'` condition and secondly the pagination (which will be a problem with big offsets and if there are many rows in total that match the above firstname condition.)

Comment: @ypercube: Disagree. The main problem is that this solution and the solution with biggest num. of votes doesn't scale well. These solutions needs bigger indexes and when page number is big (at the "end" of `ORDER BY LastName`) the performance is getting worse.

Answer (score 6):

In SQL 2012 it’s very simple:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName
  FROM person.Person
 WHERE FirstName like '%ad%'
 ORDER BY LastName
 OFFSET 10 ROWS 
 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Check out  [this link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2696/)  for other versions of SQL servers + performance comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is possible if there is an unique index on Person.Person table (ex. there is a unique index on `PersonID` column and this index is clustered - for example if you have a clustered PK). In such cases above query can be rewritten thus:

```
;WITH tmp_cte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastName) AS RowNumber, PersonID
    FROM person.Person
    WHERE FirstName like '%ad%'
)
SELECT ...
FROM Person.Person p
WHERE p.PersonID IN -- PersonID is the key of this UNIQUE INDEX
(
SELECT PersonID FROM tmp_cte 
WHERE RowNumber > @skip 10 AND RowNumber <= @Take--20
)
```

or

```
DECLARE @Rows TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY);
;WITH tmp_cte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastName) AS RowNumber, PersonID
    FROM person.Person
    WHERE FirstName like '%ad%'
)
INSERT @Rows (ID)
SELECT PersonID FROM tmp_cte 
WHERE RowNumber > @skip 10 AND RowNumber <= @Take--20

SELECT ...
FROM Person.Person p
WHERE p.PersonID IN (SELECT ID FROM @Rows); -- PersonID is the key of this UNIQUE INDEX
```

**Note #1**: In this particular case, an index on `(FirstName, LastName)` or `(LastName, FirstName)`  could be also useful.

**Note #2**: This solution should perform better if you have more columns within final `SELECT` clause.